# How to access Direct Manipulation interfaces

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am investigating Direct Manipulation support in Windows 8 Desktop applications. I found some samples online that describe some concepts in C++ but I am a C# programmer.

I want to access the COM interop interfaces for IDirectManipulationManager , IDirectManipulationCompositor etc . However, I cannot find the assembly where these interfaces are included.

> Where are the interfaces located?

I have VS 2012 utlimate and the the Windows 8 SDK installed. Are there some other installations needed for working with Direct manipulation?

Also, if anyone can provide me some more code samples (other than the ones in Intel developer website) for Direct Manipulation, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSDN contains documentation covering [DirectManipulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The interface documentation references the interface definition (DirectManipulation.idl) you can use to generate an interop assembly. With the Windows 8 SDK installed, you'll find DirectManipulation.idl in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um`

You may want to first check WPF's Manipulation events to see if they are sufficient for your scenario.

[Sample Code: Support multi-touch in WPF](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSWPF3DMultiTouch-17e457ba)

Also, search MSDN Magazine for the following articles for more info on WPF Manipulation events (unfortunately, I cannot link them currently):

- Multi-Touch Manipulation Events in WPF
- Touch and Response
- Multi-Touch Inertia

**Update:**
To create an assembly, copy DirectManipulation.idl to a temp folder.
Open the Visual Studio or SDK command prompt.

`cd` to the temp folder where the idl was copied.

Run `midl directmanipulation.idl /tlb directmanipulation.tlb` to generate a type library.

Run `directmanipulation.tlb /out:DirectManipulation.dll` to generate an assembly that can be referenced in Visual Studio.

For more info on MIDL and TLBImp, see

MIDL Command-Line Reference
msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367372(v=vs.85).aspx

MSDN: Importing a Type Library as an Assembly
msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/xwzy44e4(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: If you included a link to a page showing *how* to generate an iterop assembly from a idl file it would make this answer perfect.